# How to resolve unstaged changes not shown by "git status"

Tags: git

Consider

```
$ git status
On branch chore/nbsp-fix-2
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git rebase -i master
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

How do I work out what the unstaged changes are that are preventing git from rebasing?

Some background: Someone managed to add files with a non-breaking space (%A0) in the name. This has caused problems with the repository. The files show up as not tracked and git thinks the repository is dirty — a similar problem.

The technique I was using to correct the problem is to create a new branch before those changes were made and cherry-pick the few commits after those changes. Unfortunately I am now in this situation. I can imagine there is some other file or other remnant of that problem preventing me from moving forward. I am now in this position after cherry-picking the single commit following the bad file names.

I'm looking for suggestions for getting past this problem. What is rebase seeing that status does not see?

Comment: Try `git diff-files`, what's that say?  That's what rebase is checking.

Comment: @jthill, provide a proper answer and I'll give you credit. `git diff-files` (and `git diff`) provided the answer.

Comment: How did it happen?  I'm used to it being an untracked and ignored file that status duly ignores but is tracked in a new checkout and so git refuses to stomp on it, but that's not what happened here and I'm curious what did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out `git rebase` is a shell script in `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase`, grepping for "have unstaged changes"  in that dir gets exactly one hit, in `git-sh-setup`, in this function:

```
require_clean_work_tree () {
    git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null || exit 1
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    err=0

    if ! git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
    then
        echo >&2 "Cannot $1: You have unstaged changes."
        err=1
    fi

[ ... ]
```

and rebase does invoke that.  So, to answer

> What is rebase seeing that status does not see?

your question, try `git diff-files`.

Comment: Thank you, that’s what I was looking for. `git diff` and `git diff-files` showed that there was a 0 length file managed by git-fat that was causing the problem. There is a bug with filtered files that are 0-length.

Comment: There's even a patch supplied in the report. I made a pull request for it.

Comment: That's how I figured out what the problem was. I can verify that the change fixes the problem as well.

Comment: `git diff-files` showed the file. But what now? The file is in a directory that I moved out of the repo and and re-added as a symlink. So git seems confused about that. But what now?

Comment: What version of git are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite relevant to OP's issue but hope this might be useful for someone else. In my case `git status` didn't see **new files** in repo under certain folder. They could be staged manually but disappeared again when unstaged. And the reason was found in `.git/info/exclude` file which somehow was non-empty, apparently generated by one of my previous IDEs, long ago.